# How can I access the values of a map as a whole

Tags: c++

I have a map in c++ like this:

```
std::map<int, int> points;
```

I know that I can access the two integers  for example in a for loop like this

```
for (auto map_cntr = points.begin(); map_cntr != points.end(); ++map_cntr)
        {
          int A = map_cntr->first; // key
          int B = map_cntr->second; // val
        }
```

But I want to know how I can access every point as a whole (and not it's entries like above).

I thought something like this:

```
for (auto map_cntr = points.begin(); map_cntr != points.end(); ++map_cntr)
            {
              auto whole_point = points.at(map_cntr);
            }
```

Actually, I want to do operations on integers of a entry (point) of the map with integers of the following entry (point) of the map.

Comment: A map is an associative container, optimized for lookup of the second element using the first element as a key. Either you are doing something really peculiar, or I cannot see how it can be a good idea to use it as a point store, with one of the coordinates being the key and the other the value.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to do operations on integers of a entry (point) of the map
>   with integers of the following entry (point) of the map.

`Map` is not suited container to perform operation depending on the sequence of elements where you want to modify current element according to previous ones.  For those things you can use a vector or an array of pairs for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach loop

```
std::map<int, int> points;

for (auto pair : points)
{
    // pair - is what you need
    pair.second;
    pair.first;
    auto whole_point = pair;

}
```

Comment: To be fair OP's question is a guessing game

Comment: @KillzoneKid, yes, its a typical a/b question.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to do operations on integers of a entry (point) of the map with integers of the following entry (point) of the map

You can't directly modify the key of a [key,value] pair in a map. If you need to do so, you have to erase the pair and insert another one.

If you only need to write the value of a pair, or if you only need to read the pairs, you can do it with a single iterator, like this:

```
// assuming the map contains at least 1 element.
auto it = points.begin();

std::pair<const int, int>* currentPoint = &(*it);
it++;
for (; it != points.end(); ++it) {
    auto& nextPoint = *it;
    // Read-only: currentPoint->first, nextPoint.first
    // Read/write: currentPoint->second, nextPoint.second
    currentPoint = &nextPoint;
}
```

[Live example](http://cpp.sh/8gmrg)